# Spring cloud stream not throwing exception when zookeeper is down

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using kafka with zookeeper that comes with the kafka bundle. I'm also using spring cloud stream, and kafka binder.

I wanted to see what happens if zookeeper is down, while the kafka broker is running. I send some items to the kafka topic via spring cloud stream source. To my surprise, instead of getting an exception, spring cloud stream says it's ok. However my items aren't in the kafka queue. Is this the expected behavior, or a bug? Is there something I can configure to get an exception back if zookeeper is down?

Answer (score 1):

Try Kafka Producer `sync = true` property.

I'm afraid we can reach the Broker for metadata, but when we send a record that is done in async manner by default.

So, track down the network problems fully we have to switch to the `sync` mode.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_kafka_producer_properties

Comment: I have sync = true in my config. If the kafka broker is down, I'm getting back an exception, just not zookeeper.

Comment: OK. I think that's already not a Kafka Client responsibility to track the synchronization in the Kafka ensemble with Zookeeper controller... And we can do nothing on the matter for you.

Comment: My understanding of how Spring Cloud Stream interacts with Kafka/Zookeeper is limited, but I'd hope that with sync=true I could always count on the fact an exception would be thrown if the message is not indeed persisted in the Kafka topic.  It seems there is real potential for loss of messages in this scenario

Comment: I still think there should be some logs on the matter when you send message outside of your app to the Kafka Binder. Would be great to see DEBUG logs on the `KafkaProducerMessageHandler`. So, please, switch on DEBUG for the `org.springframework.kafka` or maybe even for the `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer` and we will be able to track what's going on.

Comment: Maybe there is something like `Timeout waiting for response from KafkaProducer` already in your logs...

Comment: I cleared out the kafka queue by deleting the topic files in kakfa-logs. Things seem to work now. Even with zookeeper down, I was able to see the  items consumed.